# Network manager wifi config with no CA certificate

Tags: network-manager

I try to reuse a network manager wifi EAP-PEAP config in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyWifi

like this :

```
[connection]
id=MyWifi
uuid=70b2f88f-1c43-45e0-acd5-276f66bd0b98
type=wifi
permissions=user:john.doe:;

[wifi]
mac-address-randomization=0
mode=infrastructure
ssid=MyWifi

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-eap

[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=john.doe
password=
phase2-auth=mschapv2

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
ip6-privacy=0
method=auto
```

But when I open it with nm-connection-editor, it says :

> Invalid setting Wi-Fi Security: invalid EAP-PEAP CA certificate: no
>   certificate specified

In fact, the "No CA certificate is required" is not marked in the Wi-Fi sercurity tab. But it was in the original configuration and I do not see how make it mark in the configuration file. [wifi with no certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNsRJ.png)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is set in dconf database.

> dconf dump /org/gnome/nm-applet/eap/70b2f88f-1c43-45e0-acd5-276f66bd0b98/
>   ignore-phase2-ca-cert=false
>   ignore-ca-cert=true

[Have a look here if you want to set this as default for all users](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Desktop_Migration_and_Administration_Guide/custom-default-values-system-settings.html)

Answer (score 1):

In NetworkManager, the connection profile is fine without having a certificate set.

However, using no certificate really makes your connection insecure. It's bad to do that accidentally, and you should have to clearly agree with that. So nm-connection-editor tries to indicate that, by forcing you to acknowledge that no certificate is required.

The  "No CA certificate is required" flag is not stored in the connection profile itself. nm-connection-editor stores it in the user settings. If you thus open a new profile without a certificate, then nm-connection-editor is adamant that you set a certificate (or confirm that it's not needed).

If you want no certificate, the solution is just to check "No CA certificate is required" box. Click "Save" and have the flag stored. The next time you open the profile in nm-connection-editor again, the checkbox will be selected and "Save" is not disabled.

Going through dconf is possible, but seems unnecessary.